# MaxStepSize for NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

Is there a way to restrict the step size used in `NonlinearModelFit`? In our applied problem, `NonlinearModelFit`, at the first stage, makes a big leap into the region where the function becomes ill-defined, and stops there. We are looking for settings that prevent this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a different method? Available methods include e.g. "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "NMinimize", and "QuasiNewton".

Comment: It's hard to give specific recommendations without the details but to add to the usual list of suspects:  (1) Better starting values (yes, I know that's more than difficult to do), and (2) rewriting the parameters so that they are on the same scale.  For (2) suppose the final parameter estimates are `a = 6*10^7` and `b =  4*10^-3`.  Then rewrite the model with `a*10^7` and  `b`/10^3 instead of using `a` and `b`, respectively.

Comment: MarcoB, you are right. Method->"Gradient" has no initial leap and converges gradually to a solution. Thank you!